# non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static content Java

Tags: java, swing, class, breeze, non-static

So i am currently teaching myself the GUI coding with a java book for college, and i understand it all but i ge this error and i am stumped.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import BreezySwing.*;
public class gui
{
    public class ConvertWithGUI extends GBFrame
    {
        private JLabel          fahrenheitLabel;
        private JLabel          celsiusLabel;
        private DoubleField     fahrenheitField;
        private DoubleField     celsiusField;
        private JButton         fahrenheitButton;
        private JButton         celsiusButton;

            public ConvertWithGUI()
            {
                fahrenheitLabel = addLabel       ("Fahrenheit" ,1,1,1,1);
                celsiusLabel    = addLabel       ("Celsius"    ,1,2,1,1);

                fahrenheitField = addDoubleField (32.0         ,2,1,1,1);
                celsiusField    = addDoubleField (0.0          ,2,2,1,1);
                fahrenheitButton= addButton      (">>>>>>"     ,3,1,1,1);
                celsiusButton   = addButton      ("<<<<<<"     ,3,2,1,1);
            }

            public void buttonClicked (JButton buttonObj)
            {
                Thermometer thermo = new Thermometer();

                if (buttonObj == fahrenheitButton)
                {
                    thermo.setFahrenheit(fahrenheitField.getNumber());
                    celsiusField.setNumber (thermo.getCelsius());
                }
                else
                {
                    thermo.setCelsius(celsiusField.getNumber());
                    fahrenheitField.setNumber (thermo.getFahrenheit());
                }
            }
            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                ConvertWithGUI theGUI = new ConvertWithGUI();
                theGUI.setSize(250, 100);
                theGUI.setVisible(true);

            }
    }
}
```

Ok so everything up to the part that is labeled:

```
ConvertWithGUI theGUI = new ConvertWithGUI();
```

results in the error. more specifically it is highlighted on this part:

```
new ConvertWithGUI();
```

Now the basic function of this program is to convert from and to Celsius. It is simple i know but i do not know what this error is, and i am typing this exact from the book. 
If anyone could help it will be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class gui
{
    ....
}
```

The above 3 statements are not needed. The name of your source file should be `ConvertwithGUI` since that should be the only public class in the file. Keep your source files simple so that they only contain one public class.

Comment: Thank you! Stupid little mistake i overlooked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your class `ConvertWithGUI` isn't static, so you need an instance of the containing class to construct it. Just

```
public static /*<-- Add this*/ class ConvertWithGUI extends GBFrame
```